# Leaflet widgets blocking bind PopUP

Tags: javascript, leaflet

On my leaflet Map, I have two widgets that i want to combined together in the same map. Ive tried many things when combining my two codes but it seems that D3SvgOverlay always 'block' my Map bind PopUp.

As you can see, If I use this code "alone", the bindPOPUp are working fine.

http://blockbuilder.org/renauld94/4a704ff30993fe35e019f3184aa31399

But when Im adding my other widget http://blockbuilder.org/renauld94/81500a71a32adaa4ee09a0b26d21ee89, the bindPOPup are not working. I think I'm superposing layers (Geojson layers) and its blocking the PopUp.

Anyways to make the bind POP working by combining my two widgets 'leaflet control search' and GeoJson D3SvgOverlay?

How I combined widgets in leaflet without effecting each others? Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: Combining those two works fine for me http://blockbuilder.org/gpetrioli/0b34ba1646d15194e5e752a6b8cb6967

Comment: The main problem is that you are using an old version of the leaflet in your code (*and an old version of the markercluster*). Moreover, if you open the browser console you will see a list of errors due to bad ordering of your scripts. Finally you also have a lot of html errors. [Here is a working version](https://pastebin.com/6yDFyHta) of your file (*i have only added the correct libraries and fixed some JS issues to make it work*)